# Site Hosting Issue

Tags: css, hosting

I'm a programmer, but in designing, I'm new and I created my first site by using HTML, CSS and Javascript and host on hostinger but after hosted, I realize that my site background color does not look good that's why I changes inside my .css file but the changes is not reflected on my site. Please tell me a solution, so that I can fix the problem.

Comment: Your CSS file will not load the new one on every request. Use browser network tab to see about this, it will be 304 (not modified). To make it load the new one as you updated the file content, add something to CSS URL. For example **/css/mystyle.css** should be **css/mystyle.css?version=1.0.1**. The query string **?version=1.0.1** is new to web browser and it will load the new one not use previous one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your browser cashed old css for your site. Try this:

1. Ctrl+F5 - refresh window with clearing cache
2. Use Incognito Window
3. Clear your browsing data